# By pass XmlElement serilization inside a Property with XmlText attribute

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a class with a string property.

```
 [Serializable]
        public class Gather
        {
            [XmlAttribute("action")]
            public string Action { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute("method")]
            public string Method { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute("timeout")]
            public string Timeout { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute("finishOnKey")]
            public string FinishOnKey { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public Say Say;

        }
        [Serializable]
        public class Say
        {
            [XmlText]
            public string Value;
        }
```

I was doing xml serilization successfully from the following code then i got to know that inside Value property of Say class i need to pass plain xml some time

```
 private string GetSpeechwithGatherXml(string value)
        {
            Say speechToText = new Say { Value = value };
            Gather gather = new Gather
            {
                Action = txtCallback.Text,
                Method = "Get",
                Timeout = Convert.ToInt32(numericMaxTime.Value).ToString(),
                FinishOnKey = "#",
                Say = speechToText
            };
            GatherResponse response = new GatherResponse { Gather = gather };
            var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(response.GetType());
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

            using (var stream = new StringWriter())
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, response, emptyNamespaces);
                return stream.ToString();
            }
        }
```

But xml tags are changing to `&lt; and &gt;` understandingly.
Any way I can by-pass this behavior in one propery (Value of Say class)

I wanted to send something like

```
<Response>
<Say>John’s phone number is, <say-as interpret-as="telephone">1234</say-as></Say>
</Response>
```

which is a valid xml

Comment: No.  Xml has special character and the open and close angle brackets (less than and greater than) are special character and have to be replaced with &lt; and &gt;

Comment: I have provided a sample xml which seems a valid xml as per https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: What items are suppose to be inner-text and which items are tag names?  Yes the string meets XML criteria.  Is "say-as" inner text or a tag?

Comment: Say contains both text as well as some inner tag as per following guideline
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#say-as

Comment: The twilio link example is wrong.  It referrers to the W3 specification which is the real requirement and is correct.  Read the W3 link in the twilio.

Comment: Can you please refer that link to me. in there documentation they want this say-as element inside a Say parent tag

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#edef_say-as